# time and performance complexity in nested for loops

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, time-complexity

I am having one object like below:

```
1 [country1, state1, district1, schoolName1, studentName1]
2 [country1, state1, district1, schoolName1, studentName2]
3 [country1, state1, district1, schoolName2, studentName1]
4 [country1, state1, district1, schoolName2, studentName2]
5 [country1, state1, district2, schoolName1, studentName1]
6 [country1, state1, district2, schoolName1, studentName2]
.
.
.
1000 [country3, state4, district2, schoolName2, studentName1]
1001 [country3, state4, district2, schoolName2, studentName2]
.
.
```

Now I want to segregate those like below:

```
[country1]
    [state1]
        [district1]
                [schoolname1]
                    [studentname1,studentName2,...]
                [schoolname2]
                    [studentname1,studentName2,...]
                .
                .
        [district2]
                .
                .
[country2]
    [state1]
        [district1]
                [schoolname1]
                    [studentname1,studentName2,...]
                [schoolname2]
                    [studentname1,studentName2,...]
                .
                .
        [district2]
                [schoolName1]
                    .
                    .
```

As far as I know, I can use nested `for` loops. But it consume more time and performance. I know that is bad idea. If any you have came across this situation, please share your experience to resolve this.

Comment: What do all those `[some text here]` mean? Is that a data-structure or do you want to print text like that?

Comment: Sorry. I need the object like that. For example: 1 Country object should have nested state objects, one state object should have multiple district objects. etc.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal complexity for your task (the best performance you can possibly get) is on the scale of your input, i.e. `number of rows` * `number of items in each row`. You cannot get any better, because you at least must read all the input once since you need all the data.

At the same time, your task should be do-able with this complexity.

So, if you're using two nested loops (one for rows, another one for columns), you're doing good - this will perform about the right amount of operations. If you're using as many nested loops as there are columns, you're doing a poor job (`rows ^ columns` instead of just `rows * columns`) and should try a different approach - with a task like this, you only need to read every row once, process it and add the result to the right place in your hierarchical structure.